# Angular directive template css class change delayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Code snippet from my angular directive class:

```
if (currentIndex < newMessages.length) {
  scope.message = newMessages[currentIndex];
} else {
  scope.message = newMessages[0];
}                        

$timeout(function () {
  var msgText = $('#msg-text');
  console.log("xx:" + msgText.attr('class'));
  // has-image no-desc no-desc-remove
});
```

When I change the scope.message, angular refreshes the template, and $timeout ensures that its containing function is called after the template is updated with new elements, etc. Right?

It seems it's working, but the problem is, I got classes like "has-image no-desc **no-desc-remove**". Later it's changed to "has-image".

How can I catch and event, where the classes are fully updated? Because This is no good for my code logic.

Comment: What is the piece of code that changing your classes  `"has-image no-desc no-desc-remove"` into `"has-image"` ?

Comment: <div id="msg-text" class="{{ message.imageURL ? ' has-image' : ' no-image' }}{{ message.Description ? ' has-desc' : ' no-desc' }}"> in directive template. When scope.message is changed, it updated automatically.

Comment: I will prepare you an answer really quick ---- **P.S.** Next time just try to include all the things that related with your code. Because in angluar view does an important job too (without it none can help with your question)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I catch and event, where the classes are fully updated? Because This is no good for my code logic.

By you code and requirement, you need to know the moment when your `$scope.message.imageURL` and `$scope.message.Description` updated. For the most basic way you can go with `$scope.$watchGroup()`

Example of $watchGroup. (Here I put the condition for both has some value you can adjust the condition in the way you wanted)

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['message.imageURL', 'message.Description'], function (newValues, oldValues){

  // newValues[0] => is => $scope.message.imageURL
  // newValues[1] => is => $scope.message.Description

  // case of both having some value
  if(newValues[0] &&  newValues[1]){
    console.log('things has been changed');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had angular-animate.js included in my html, and it automatically does "Class and ngClass animation hooks". More here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations. Disabled it where needed with $animate.enabled(false, myElement);